# How could having multiple images influence the speed of the app

Tags: java, performance

**The more images are currently in the sketch the slower image() runs which results in framerate lowering.
What could be causing this?**

```
//for each obstacle
for (int i=0; i<obsList.size(); i+=1){
ObstacleInstance = obsList.get(i);

  //if inside moving zone
  if (obsList.get(i).ObstacleX < 1920 + 400 && 0 - 400 
     obsList.get(i).ObstacleX) { 

      ObstacleInstance.move();

      //draws image in sketch; has performance issue
      image(ObstacleInstance.ObstacleImg, 
        ObstacleInstance.ObstacleX, 
        ObstacleInstance.ObstacleHeightFromTop,
        ObstacleInstance.ObstacleSizeX, 
        ObstacleInstance.ObstacleSizeY);
    }
  }
}
```

PS: used timer to see the time image() took to run and it increased with more images and decreased after removing them.

Comment: Did you something like `Image ObstacleInstance = obsList.get(i);`?

Comment: Yes, I just didn't show it.

Answer (score 1):

One remark first: variables and fields should start with a small letter.

Every drawn image costs.

If the width and height of an object is not fixed (400), use something like:

```
final int visibleX = 0;
final int visibleY = 0;
final int visibleSizeX = 1920;
final int visibleSizeY = 1080;

for (Obstacle obs: obsList) {
    if (obs.ObstacleX < visibleX + visibleSizeX
            && obs.ObstacleX + obs.ObstacleSizeX > visibleX) { 
            && obs.ObstacleY < visibleY + visibleSizeY
            && obs.ObstacleY + obs.ObstacleSizeY > visibleY) { 
        ObstacleInstance.move();

        image(obs.ObstacleImg, 
            obs.ObstacleX, 
            obs.ObstacleHeightFromTop,
            obs.ObstacleSizeX, 
            obs.ObstacleSizeY);
    }
}
```

Overlapped drawing costs too, but is hard to optimize, other than with *regions*, collected areas (rectangles here).

Then the `image` call seems to be slow.

- The image must not be drawn pixel by pixel.
- The image must not be loaded from file every time.
- Depending on the graphics implementation there you might hold the image
  in appropriate form (not packed bytes of a JPEG image).
- There exists 2D transformations.

It seems you are working with some visualization library.

- Look into *affine transformaions* like *translate*.
- Implementation: `System.arraycopy` is faster than a for-loop.

To check the speed, it would be nice to draw rectangle outlines i.o. images.
And `move()` should (hopefully) be substantial, not 0 or 1.